# Failed to fetch when it in fact works

Tags: javascript, html, api

```js
function unsubscribe() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var email = document.getElementById("inputEmail").value;
    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch("https://api.sendgrid.com/api/unsubscribes.add.json?api_user=[username]&api_key=[pass]&email" + email, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('Error!', error));
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <button onclick="unsubscribe()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Unsubscribe</button>
</form>
```

The request in fact works. When I check my sendgrid dashboard, I see that the email has been added to the unsubscribe list. And when I try the request in POSTMAN, I get a proper response. But console always returns `Failed to fetch`.

Comment: Check your console for CORS errors.

Comment: Verifying a request in postman does not mean it will work in javascript, as per zero298's point.  Postman requests are not subject to CORS restrictions.

Comment: @Taplar I'm aware, but I'm dumbstruck as to how it actually went through and updated on my sendgrid dashboard. That call should've never went through, when I check the networks tab it's clear that it failed. And as zero298 pointed out there is a CORS error. Tested it multiple times too. It fails in the console everytime but updates in the SendGrid dashboard

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get the error about this line `event.preventDefault();` since you don't mention `event` anywhere in your code that you provided.